# retriving hearders in all pages of word

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am exporting data from php page to word,, there i get 'n' number of datas in each page .... How to set the maximum number of data that a word page can contain ,,,, I want only 20 datas in a single page

This is the coding i use to export the data to word
i got the data in word format but the headers are not available for all the pages
ex:
Page:1
    slno    name         country            state        Town
    1       vivek        india             tamilnadu     trichy
    2       uday         india             kerala        coimbatore
   like this i am getting many details 
but in my 
page:2
      i dont get the headers like name country state and town....But i can get the details
 like
           kumar          america         xxxx            yyyy

i want the result to be  like 
  slno         name       country     state     town
   n           chris       newzealand ghgg         jkgj

Can i get the headers
If it is not possible Is there anyway to limit the number of details being displayed in each page

" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "
" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//select database
$Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't select database:
" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "
" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//execute query
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:
" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "
" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_dump.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j

Comment: It would be nice if you made an effort to format your question.

Comment: @mike B I will try it while asking next quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an if loop beneath your for loops:

```
FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
 {
   if($j<20){
     ...rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading that horrid blob of junk correctly, you're simply dumping your database out as comma-seperated values (.csv) text, and forcing it to load in different Office programs by setting MIME headers.

You're not actually creating a .doc or a .xls file, you're generating .csv file. The fact that you're tricking Office into loading the data into Word of Excel doesn't change that fact. CSV data has no formatting whatsoever. There's no page breaks, no fonts, no headers, no footers, no way to specify how many lines on a page, nothing. There's just data: data fields seperated by commas, each line representing a record.